# Related Rates Question...What formula would I use to solve this?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A rectangle is changing width and height continuously. When the width is $20 \rm{cm}$ and the area is $100 \rm{cm}^2$, the width is increasing at a rate of $3\rm{cm s}^{-1}$ and the area is increasing at a rate of $11 
\rm{cm}^2\rm {s}^{-1}$. At this moment, what is the rate of change of the height?

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer correct so that people know that the answer is an accepted answer/a good answer. And finally, welcome to MSE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $A(t)=w(t)h(t)$ (all functions of time, because they change over time), and after differentiating with respect to time, we get
$$A'=w'h_0+h'w_0$$
and we know $w_0=20$ and $h_0=5$, so
$$11 cm^2s^{-1} = 3cms^{-1}*5cm+h'cms^{-1}*20cm$$

Comment: Why does A′=w′h+h′w work?

Comment: I edited the post, see if you understand that

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you!